# last and first content in loop or output (coldfusion)

Tags: database, loops, coldfusion

I wonder if there is possible to display specific content taken from the Loop or Output in ColdFusion, for example i have an output:

```
<cfoutput query="get_service_plus"><b>#SUBJECT#</b><br/>#plus_content#<br/></cfoutput>
```

and its query, just in case:

```
<cfquery name="GET_SERVICE_PLUS" datasource="#DSN3#">
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        SERVICE_PLUS
    WHERE   
        SERVICE_ID = #attributes.action_id#
      <cfif isDefined("GET_SERVICE_PLUS.SERVICE_PLUS_ID")>
        AND SERVICE_PLUS_ID = #GET_SERVICE_PLUS.SERVICE_PLUS_ID#
      </cfif>
      ORDER BY PLUS_DATE DESC,RECORD_DATE DESC
</cfquery>
```

i know that i most probably should use the loops to get the specific content from db but  couldn't understand how to achieve it... thx for help!

Comment: Make sure you use `<cfqueryparam>` to avoid SQL injection. Also what database server are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do.

If you are looping the complete query you can check your current row number by using the variable "qet_service_plus.currentrow", so

```
<cfif qet_service_plus.currentrow eq 1>
   <!--- do first row display stuff --->
</cfif>
```

With every query also comes the number of records returned in the query. You can find this in "recordcount", so

```
<cfif get_service_plus.currentrow eq get_service_plus.recordcount>
   <!--- do last row display stuff --->
</cfif>
```

If you want to get to a specific record in a query without going through the complete query you can treat a cfquery as an associative array. eg.

```
<cfoutput>
<!--- service id in first record --->
#get_service_plus['service_id'][1]# 
<!--- service id in last record --->
#get_service_plus['service_id'][get_service_plus.recordcount]# 
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: +1 very comprehensive. I'd still do that at the database level to avoid reading very large record sets.

Comment: Definitely.  If you know you want the newest and oldest (based on the fact that the query above is sorted by date fields) then it is relatively trivial to a where clause to return the records based on max/min date.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it from a CF perspective:

```
<cfoutput query="get_service_plus">

  <cfif get_service_plus.currentRow eq 1 or get_service_plus.currentRow eq get_service_plus.recordCount>
    <b>#SUBJECT#</b><br/>#plus_content#<br/>
  </cfif>

</cfoutput>
```

You could also do this using a query of queries once you have the initial recordset back.

I would suggest you try and grab the first and last row at the database layer like you suggest as that is much more efficient, especially for large record sets.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No need for an increment value in a simple query loop.  Every query has "currentrow" and "recordcount". See the docs for cfquery usage : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae__WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec19562-7f4c